# NodeJS native module - how to remove debug symbols

Tags: c++, node.js, debug-symbols

I'm writing a native module for Node but would like to remove the debugging information.
I'm using node-gyp to build the module.

It's doing a release build, but still, the symbol table is included in the output file.

So I need to remove it with the strip Unix command after the build. 
Is there a way to remove it in the build itself - ie. specify something in the .gyp file?

Furthermore, even after stripping the debug symbols, I can still use

```
strings [node-module]
```

And it lists the names of my functions. Is it possible to remove these also?

This is the command I use to build the native module:

```
node-gyp rebuild --target=v8.9.4
```

And this is my binding.gyp:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "libraries": [
          "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so",
          "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.58.0"
      ],
      "target_name": "utils",
      "sources": [ "src/native/utils.cpp" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What compiler are You using? Maybe You are not specifying that You don't want **any** debug symbols

Comment: @bartop I edited the question with more details

Comment: @LachoTomov can you try with the flags `--release --no-debug`

Comment: @JibyJose tried it, still the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know, a node native module is a dynamic library. You
cannot strip the dynamic symbol table from a dynamic library because the
dynamic symbol table is necessary at runtime for dynamically linking the library.
Even `strip --strip-all` will not remove the dynamic symbol table. `strip --strip-all` or `strip --strip-unneeded`
strips everything that *can* be stripped from a dynamic library. Adding `-g0` to the compilation flags
eliminates all *debugging* information, but symbol tables contain more than
debugging information.

You can instruct the linker to do the same thing as `strip --strip-all` at
linktime by passing it the option `-s|--strip-all`. To do this, your `binding.gyp`
would be:

```
{
    "targets": [
    {
        "libraries": [
            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so",
            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.58.0"
        ],
        "target_name": "utils",
        "ldflags" : [ "-Wl,-s" ],
        "sources": [ "src/native/utils.cpp" ],
    }
  ]
}
```

The resulting node module is then as stripped as a shared library can be:

```
$ file ./build/Release/utils.node
./build/Release/utils.node: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, \
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, \
BuildID[sha1]=eb53cee5839c71b41176bc7a852802035009e8ae, stripped
                                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I have searched a bit and there may be a brute force solution of specifying the compiler flag `-g0` manually. Take a look here:https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/26 . So following Your example and advices given in the github issue the input file should be like this:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "libraries": [
          "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so",
          "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.58.0"
      ],
      "target_name": "utils",
      "cflags_cc": [ "-g0" ]
      "sources": [ "src/native/utils.cpp" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Sadly, there is no way for me to test it and it is not platform independant.

Comment: Thanks, tried it, plus the different "cflags" variations from the link, but unfortunately still the same.